# Why is the last case in a case_when sequence often referred to as TRUE?

Tags: r, dplyr

I know that this case defines what to do when none of the prior cases were satisfied, but why is it called "TRUE" rather than say "ELSE"?

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(new = case_when(
    cyl == 4 ~ "weak",
    cyl == 6 ~ "medium",
    TRUE ~ "other"
  ))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as `?case_when` says,

> The LHS must evaluate to a logical vector.

This implies that things like ELSE are not allowed as it is not a logical value. But one may still wonder, say, why we can't use FALSE.

Here's how everything works in your example. First we look across all the rows for cases where `cyl == 4` is `TRUE` and set the corresponding new values to `"weak"`. Second, among the *remaining* rows we look for such that `cyl == 6` is `TRUE` and use `"medium"` there. If we stop here, then

> If no cases match, NA is returned.

So, how do we deal with the remaining rows then? `TRUE` (using recycling) is trivially `TRUE` in each remaining case, allowing to return `"other"`.

Thus, it's a combination of the LHS having to be logical and the sequential way of dealing with the specified cases.